# Identify specific class of array element?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array (Element[]) that contains different implementations.

Now, what's the proper way to identify the "subclass"/type of an array element?
i.e. how do I identify Element[1] as an implementation of RedElement?

```
export interface Element {
   ...
}
```

```
export class RedElement implements Element {
    ...specific functionality/values.
}

export class GreenElement implements Element {
    ...specific functionality/values.
}
```

```
const myArr: Element[] = [
    new GreenElement(...params),
    new GreenElement(...otherParams),
    new RedElement(...),
...
]
```

Now when I later want to work with one of those elements I need to know which type/class it is, but all I'm left with is an Object of type `Element`.

```
myArr.forEach(e => {
    e <- has type Element
});
```

I could obviously add a property that identifies each element as its specific class by a string or enum but that seems not too elegant.

Is there a better way?

Comment: You could use `(GreenElement | RedElement)[]` and check then `if(el instanceof GreenElement)` etc

Comment: `instanceof` did not work for me due to an incorrect import... now works like a charm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are creating classes, you can use `instanceof` operator to discriminate between your different elements.

```
myArr.forEach(e => {
    if (e instanceof RedElement) {
        ...
    }
});
```